# Ajax – Get data from three different sources asynchronously but append in the order the Ajax function is called

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, append

I'm developing on WordPress and using the pages of posts that are generated by WordPress. With Ajax, I grab the post markup from the next page and append it to the current page so that the user never actually uses pages but instead gets more posts when he/she clicks a button to load more posts. Please see what I currently have here: [biomane.infowest.com/news](http://biomane.infowest.com/news). I have been trying to figure this out every way I know how so now I'm asking the SO community.

I've gotten the code to a functional point but it's unacceptable performance to me. Especially when I know I'm doing it wrong (i.e. not the best/right way)

I have WordPress set to generate only one post on each page. But I want to load three posts at a time. So I use a conditional statement to check if there are at least three pages of posts and then I grab the post from each of the next three pages and append it. (I don't tell WordPress to load three at a time because on smaller screens I will load only 1 or 2 at a time).

However, the loading and appending of posts happens in whatever order of speed that they are grabbed if I just call the Ajax code three times in a row. I have done it this way when page very first loads so that you can see it. I love how much faster it is. But posts showing in an out of date order isn't acceptable. So I'm trying other code on the "Load More" button being clicked. Here, each Ajax call for a post must complete before loading in another. That's where I know I'm not using the best code nor logic. It's too slow. Here is the main piece of code that only loads the next post after the previous has loaded, until three total posts are loaded and appended:

```
function ajax_load_3_posts() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $next_page_link,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            // Get the "div.post" and append it to the posts container
            $posts_container_el.append( $(data).find('div.post') );
            // Update $next_page_num and $next_page_link variables for next conditionals
            ++$next_page_num;
            $next_page_link = $next_page_link.replace(/\/page\/[0-9]*/, '/page/' + $next_page_num);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: $next_page_link,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data) {
                    // Get the "div.post" and append it to the posts container
                    $posts_container_el.append( $(data).find('div.post') );
                    // Update $next_page_num and $next_page_link variables for next conditionals
                    ++$next_page_num;
                    $next_page_link = $next_page_link.replace(/\/page\/[0-9]*/, '/page/' + $next_page_num);
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $next_page_link,
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function(data) {
                            // Get the "div.post" and append it to the posts container
                            $posts_container_el.append( $(data).find('div.post') );
                            // Update $next_page_num and $next_page_link variables for next conditionals
                            ++$next_page_num;
                            $next_page_link = $next_page_link.replace(/\/page\/[0-9]*/, '/page/' + $next_page_num);
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    });
}
```

I have WordPress passing in information that I use for the variables, such as the page number and next page's URL. So the functionality is there. My question is about loading the Ajax data asynchronously yet in the order that I write the Ajax call—and not how I'm currently doing it where I call the next Ajax function on the previous Ajax completion which is essentially the same as setting asynch to false.

This has been very difficult for me because I will certainly admit that I'm novice when it comes to programming. But I just need you to get me a little further on this one. So thank you for your help and have a great day!

Comment: since this a server and client side question, posting the relevant server side query could help.

My initial observation is simply don't send next/page in the ajax. Instead generate those variables server side and run a query that limits the output to 3 results and simply output all three in a single call.

Comment: I understand that logic and I really like that, @imvain2 Thank you! I just don't even really know where to get started with that since I'm no PHP or WordPress expert either. I'm trying to learn though  Could you possibly point me in the right direction if I were to approach it from that angle?

Comment: Do you mean something along the lines of [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/p5ujumjd/2/)? I also agree with imvain2 that if you're trying to load many posts it's better to do it in one server request.

Comment: Thank you for the code, @Stryner However, I tried implementing it and it loads the data (posts) in whatever order they are grabbed by speed of the server. So it's basically random each time the page is loaded. I added `$posts_container_el.append( $(data).find('div.post') );` after `nextAjax && nextAjax();`